# Sequelize Op.or with two Op.and

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I need get WHERE query like this:

```
WHERE (x = 1 AND y = 2) OR (x = 2 AND y = 1)
```

In sequelize i write:

```
where: {
          [Op.or]: {
            [Op.and]: {
              ownerId: candidate.recipientId,
              recipientId: candidate.senderId,
            },
            [Op.and]: {
              recipientId: candidate.recipientId,
              ownerId: candidate.senderId,
            },
          },
        },
```

But i get:

```
WHERE (("Chat"."recipient_id" = 2 AND "Chat"."owner_id" = 1))
```

Comment: use `[Op.and]: <array>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
where: {
  [Op.or]: [{
    ownerId: candidate.recipientId,
    recipientId: candidate.senderId,
  },{
    recipientId: candidate.recipientId,
    ownerId: candidate.senderId,
  }]
}
```